# Google Map Search Box APi, searchbox not showing after initial load

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

So I am using the google map api with search box

I.e. here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

In my DOM I have the following html

```
<div id="mapdialog">
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

And then the google API get's called when the user hits my "map" button

```
$("#gMap,#gMapSide").click(function () {
    var geoUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + county + "&sensor=true";
    $.ajax({
        url: geoUrl,
        context: document.body
    }).done(function (data) {
        ne = data.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast;
        se = data.results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest;
        initialize(ne.lat, ne.lng, se.lat, se.lng);
    });
    return false;
});
```

And when this is first clicked the MAP works fine, the search box is displayed. But when the user hit's the map button second time, the map still loads fine but there is no search box.

If you look at the google initialize code, it grabs the box and pushes it onto the map

```
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

So I think that's why there is no searchbox second click because it's gone from the DOM ?

Any suggestions would be welcome !

Comment: Can you prove that? As in if you open dev tools after the first button press and refresh the html is the input gone from the DOM?

Comment: aye it's gone, it gets pushed google map control. But then second time it's clicked it's not even in google map control anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less of an answer and more of a workaround. If you wrap your control in a div like so:

```
<div id="inputWrapper">
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
</div>
```

Then you could reattach it each time using jQuery?

```
$("#gMap,#gMapSide").click(function () {
    //Instantiate Variable
    var pac-input = '<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">';
    //Append to element.
    pac-input.appendTo($('#inputWrapper'));
    var geoUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + county + "&sensor=true";
    $.ajax({
        url: geoUrl,
        context: document.body
    }).done(function (data) {
        ne = data.results[0].geometry.viewport.northeast;
        se = data.results[0].geometry.viewport.southwest;
        initialize(ne.lat, ne.lng, se.lat, se.lng);
    });
    return false;
});
```

*EDIT*

Perhaps a simpler solution, could you not attach a jquery object instead of a dom element to the google function like so:

```
var pac-input = '<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">';
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
    pac-input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

Be aware, that is untested and may not work as expected.

*Another Edit*

Another option would be to clone the original element into the maps call possibly.

```
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
    document.getElementById('pac-input').clone());
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

Hope one of these helps!

Answer (score 2):

What I have done is creating a DOM input element as a simple string and then appending it to the division where you keep the map, in your case, `#mapdialog`. Afterwards, it could be simply picked up using `document.getElementById()` and that element could be given as the input to the new `google.maps.places.SearchBox()` as the input. Look at the below snippet.

```
    var pacinput = "<input id='pac-input' class='controls' type='text' placeholder='Search Box' />";
    $('#mapdialog').append(pacinput);
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```

However the options given by Swires are not really working for me. In my case that has triggered an `Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined.` That may be because I am writing the javascript as a PHP string when the document loads. Not very sure of the exact reason.